# Akka events between local and remote actors

Tags: scala, akka, akka-remote-actor

Using the event bus mechanism between actors in the same `ActorSystem` is straight-forward, but I was wondering if there was a sanctioned method for doing so between:

- Actors in different `ActorSystems` in the same JVM
- Actors in different JVMs (via remoting)

Assuming that I know the paths to the actors is fine, but if there was a commonly used mechanism to discover those kinds of things as well, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case you need to look for distributed publish-subscribe on a cluster, supposing you want to subscribe actors to events, without awareness of the location of the actors. This [link](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/distributed-pub-sub.html) may prove useful.

This is a note from the [official Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/event-bus.html):

> The event stream is a local facility, meaning that it will not
>   distribute events to other nodes in a clustered environment (unless
>   you subscribe a Remote Actor to the stream explicitly). If you need to
>   broadcast events in an Akka cluster, without knowing your recipients
>   explicitly (i.e. obtaining their ActorRefs), you may want to look
>   into: Distributed Publish Subscribe in Cluster.

Comment: Note that the first link is dead.